# not allowed truncated value in group by [criteria API]?

Tags: jpa, group-by, criteria-api

I have a query like :

```
select name, trunc( date, 'MM' ), sum( number )
from t$mytable
group by name, trunc( date, 'MM' );
```

which runs perfectly, and gives expected result. 
I implemented exactly the same query in JPA criteria API :

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery( pClass );
Metamodel metamodel = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType entityType_ = metamodel.entity( pClass );
Root<?> root = criteriaQuery.from( pClass );

Expression pathName = root.get( entityType_.getSingularAttribute( "name" ));
Path pathDate = root.get( entityType_.getSingularAttribute( "date" ) );
Expression<Date> pathTruncatedDate = criteriaBuilder.function("trunc", Date.class , pathDate, 'MM');
Expression pathNumber = criteriaBuilder.sum( root.get( entityType_.getSingularAttribute("number") ));

criteriaQuery.select( criteriaBuilder.array( pathName,  pathTruncatedDate, pathNumber) );

List<Expression> groupBy = new ArrayList<Expression>();
groupBy.add( pathName);
groupBy.add( pathTruncatedDate);
criteriaQuery.groupBy( groupBy );
TypedQuery<Object[]> q = em.createQuery( criteriaQuery );
```

<-- and surprisingly I got ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression by running it. What coused the problem, everything is on right place, i guess.
Thank You very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it's not look like Oracle question but,
what about creating view by your statement and using view in your application?
something like

```
create view vw_my_table as
select name, trunc( date, 'MM' ), sum( number )
from t$mytable
group by name, trunc( date, 'MM' );
```

Comment: thank You for your response. I made the view, and selected from that, which runs perfectly right away. However I can't figure out why does not work without additional view table. I'd rather skip solution using view table. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: suppose it's some restriction of criteriaBuilder I think that if you will use simple query it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and have found the root cause of this ORA-00979.

Oracle automatically handle aggregation of date in below query

```sql
select name, trunc( date, 'MM' ), sum( number )
from t$mytable
group by name, trunc( date, 'MM' );
```

With Criteria API you need to use criteria builder `least` method.

In your cas you just need to replace select line with:

```
criteriaQuery.select( criteriaBuilder.array( pathName,  criteriaBuilder.least(pathTruncatedDate), pathNumber) );
```